# Collect list item according to name and store in array or object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dual list in which you get an option to add left list item in right list. And right list is a form. Now i am stuck at a problem where when user click the submit button all the li in right list and there inside values get store in an object with there specific name div id name. I have worked on it for 5 days now but unable to collect data according to div id name. Like

```
<div id="name1"> 
<input id="tts" type="text" value="${CTLIST.tts}"> s<br>
 <input id="topic_level" type="text" value="${CTLIST.topic_level}"><br> 
 <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[4]}</label> <input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.to_be_shown_individually && 'checked')}> <br>
  <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[3]}</label><input id="check_for_geometry" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.check_for_geometry && 'checked')}><br>
</div>
```

Suppose this is an li of right list.
I want data to get stored like

```
{
[name : name1,
tts.value : 10, 
ifcheckboxcheck : true,
],
[name : name2,
tts.value : 10, 
ifcheckboxcheck : true,]
}
```

HEre is my html

```
    <section class="ctList">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="dual-list list-left col-md-5">
                    <div class="well text-right">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"><i class="fa fa-search"
                                            aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 20px;"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="search" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group" id="La">

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="list-arrows col-md-1 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-left">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    </button>

                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm move-right">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="dual-list list-right col-md-5">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default selector" title="select all"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="SearchDualList" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="search" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <form id="rightData" method="POST">
                            <ul class="list-group" id="accordian">

                                <!-- right list  -->

                            </ul>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is my js  which is obviously not working

```
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.listelement').on('click', function () {
            if (!($(this).children('.content').is(':visible'))) {
                $('.content').slideUp();
                $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('.content').slideUp();
            }
        });

        $(function () {

            $('body').on('click', '.list-group .list-group-item', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });
            $('.list-arrows button').click(function () {
                var $button = $(this), actives = '';
                if ($button.hasClass('move-left')) {
                    actives = $('.list-right ul li.active');
                    actives.clone().appendTo('.list-left ul');
                    actives.remove();
                } else if ($button.hasClass('move-right')) {
                    actives = $('.list-left ul li.active');
                    actives.clone().appendTo('.list-right ul');
                    actives.remove();
                }
            });
            $('.dual-list .selector').click(function () {
                var $checkBox = $(this);
                if (!$checkBox.hasClass('selected')) {
                    $checkBox.addClass('selected').closest('.well').find('ul li:not(.active)').addClass('active right');
                    $checkBox.children('i').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked').addClass('glyphicon-check');
                } else {
                    $checkBox.removeClass('selected').closest('.well').find('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
                    $checkBox.children('i').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
                }
            });
            $('[name="SearchDualList"]').keyup(function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == '9') return;
                if (code == '27') $(this).val(null);
                var $rows = $(this).closest('.dual-list').find('.list-group li');
                var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                $rows.show().filter(function () {
                    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                    return !~text.indexOf(val);
                }).hide();
            });

        });

        ////printing properties

        $(function () {
            var ctList = [];
            var ctRight = [];

            var $tBody = $("#La");
            var $rbody = $("#accordian");

            $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/d6n2a', function (data) {
                data.topic_info.qt_ct_connection.map(value => {
                    value.ct_list.forEach((CTLIST) => {

                        $tBody.append(`<li class="list-group-item" id="rl">
                        <span id="nameOfCt">${CTLIST.ct}</span>
                                <a href="#${CTLIST.ct}" class="btn btn-danger show" data-toggle="collapse">View More</a>

                         <div id="${CTLIST.ct}" class="collapse valueDiv">
                              <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[2]}</label> <input id="tts" type="text" value="${CTLIST.tts}"><br>
                              <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[1]}</label> <input id="topic_level" type="text" value="${CTLIST.topic_level}"><br> 
                                <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[4]}</label> <input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.to_be_shown_individually && 'checked')}> <br>
                              <label>${Object.keys(CTLIST)[3]}</label><input id="check_for_geometry" type="checkbox" ${(CTLIST.check_for_geometry && 'checked')}><br>
                     </div>        

                        </li>`);



                    });
                })
            })
        })



    </script>



    <script>
        var SendDataObject = {};


        $("#rightData").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var IDs = [];
            var list = {};
             var data = {} ;
var tts = {};
            let rightListLength;
            rightListLength = $('#rightData li').length;
            var tts = [];
         $("#rightData li").each(function (){
            $("#rightdata").find("div").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); 
            $('#rightData').find("#tts").each(function () { IDs.push(this.value)})
         })
        });

            // $('#rightData li').each(function () {
            //  var a =  $(this).html();
            //     console.log("i am writin second", list[$(this).attr('value')] = $(this).html());
            //     console.log(list[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).html())          
            // });
console.log(IDs)
console.log(tts)

CSS
```

```
<style>
    .ctList {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .ctList .dual-list .list-group {
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .ctList .list-left li,
    .list-right li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .ctList .list-arrows {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .ctList .list-arrows button {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .dual-list.list-left .well li.list-group-item .show {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

```
This is rendered HTML in browser if ony one li in right list . ANd if two li then another HTML will be rendered by diffrent i name coming from json and value .
```

point_in_first_quad
                                View More

```
                     <div id="point_in_first_quad" class="collapse valueDiv">
                          <label>tts</label> <input id="tts" type="text" value="10"><br>
                          <label>topic_level</label> <input id="topic_level" type="text" value="capable"><br> 
                            <label>to_be_shown_individually</label> <input id="to_be_shown_individually" type="checkbox" checked=""> <br>
                          <label>check_for_geometry</label><input id="check_for_geometry" type="checkbox" checked=""><br>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the rendered html in the browser in *right list* and what is the output expected from that list too?

Comment: I have pasted in post. The output i want is in json format already mentioned

Comment: i mean html generated inside #accordion its empty in the html that you pasted

Comment: yes at first it will be empty . User will add item like drag and drop in right list. It is pushed by js in right list

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your html to include classes or some other identifier, since you cannot have two elements with same ids, things like **#topic_level**, Probably add a class to help with selection, something like below should help

```
<div id="point_in_first_quad" class="collapse valueDiv">
   <label class="tts-label">tts</label> <input id="tts" class="tts-value" type="text" value="10"><br>...
```

You added classes to element you want to use in your result.

Adjust the following to make your result object

```
var finalResult = [];
$('#accordion div').each(function(index, item) {
  var $it = $(item);
  var ob = {};
  ob['name'] = $it.find('.tts-label').text();
  ob['tts.value'] = $it.find('.tts-value').val();
  ob['ifcheckboxcheck'] = $it.find('[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked");
  finalResult.push(ob);
});
```

Since you have two checkbox field, add a class selector to the one you want to use in result.

Comment: Its not working if you have two li in right list. It is pushing same values in object as it gets on first number

Comment: Can you update your original question with changes that you have tried?